# When installing supervisord, how to get it to start on reboots?

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

I'm on a ubuntu server, once I install supervisord will it start on reboots?

How can I find this out?

Answer (score 1):

Simply reboot and see if it starts :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sysv-rc-conf for Ubuntu where Centos or similar might use chkconfig

if it isnt already installed

```
sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

then

```
sysv-rc-conf supervisord on
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have a script /etc/init.d/supervisor or similar and that there are relevant symlinks in /etc/rc?.d. If not something like

```
update-rc.d supervisor defaults
```

should do the trick once you get a start script into /etc/init.d.

Having said that, if you install supervisor from a package and it didn't install and setup a start script, you are entitled to complain to the package maintainer.

Comment: If you dont have it you can create the /etc/init.d/supervisord file, I pasted it right here: https://gist.github.com/3276450